# Trying to modify input value through DOM access with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to add a value (name) passed in as a parameter to an input element through DOM access. Here 'this' is a table row and I am trying to give table data 0 the value of name.

```
let tr = $(this).parent().parent(), tds = tr.children();
$(tds[0]).html(`<input type='text' name='name' />`);
$(tds[0]).child.val(name);
```

The input box shows up in the table but not the name. The error I get in the browser console is

```
Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
```

Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: Any reason for not adding the attribute `value` directly?

Comment: Only that I didn't know the proper syntax to do so. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

- use the `.closest()` method
- use the `.eq()` method to filter out a specific TD by index
- Assign the value directly to the input

```js
const $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
const $tds = $tr.children("td");
$tds.eq(0).html(`<input type='text' name='name' value="${name}" />`);
```